# PHP segfault with non root user

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nextcloud

I've configured an `Ubuntu-22.04` server with `Nextcloud-24.0.4`, `Apache-2.4.52` and `php-8.1.2`,
all it's working apart from the background jobs launched by `www-data`.

After I've enabled [caching](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/caching_configuration.html), php goes wild with non root user.

If I run the php executable with any user that is not root the executable immediately goes in "Segmentation fault". I've lost many hours/days looking at the logs, changing php.ini (memory_limit, apc.enable_cli, etc.) or nextcloud's config.php.
But nothing, so it's starting to get frustrating...

Any advice?

If it can help here are the php and apache modules loaded:

APACHE

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

PHP

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

UPDATE

As per the advice of arkascha, here it is the coredump, any suggestions?

```bash
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.0.90-0ubuntu1) 12.0.90
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php8.1...
(No debugging symbols found in /usr/bin/php8.1)
[New LWP 85430]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f8e5c2dacfb in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x0) at ./libio/iofclose.c:48
48  ./libio/iofclose.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f8e5c2dacfb in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x0) at ./libio/iofclose.c:48
#1  0x00005621ae81ee00 in ?? ()
#2  0x00005621ae74ec9c in ?? ()
#3  0x00005621ae747dea in php_module_startup ()
#4  0x00005621ae8939f1 in ?? ()
#5  0x00005621ae5f2559 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f8e5c285d90 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x5621ae5f23d0, argc=argc@entry=3,
    argv=argv@entry=0x7ffedd005dd8) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#7  0x00007f8e5c285e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x5621ae5f23d0, argc=3, argv=0x7ffedd005dd8, init=<optimized out>,
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffedd005dc8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#8  0x00005621ae5f2915 in _start ()
```

Comment: I too have had a hard time with php/apache on Ubuntu 22.  I went back to Ubuntu 20.

Comment: With a segmentation fault you need to create a core dump for that crash (you have to temporarily enable that in your system) and then use that in an IDE with the source code of php loaded. That way you can see exactly what actually crashes and why.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @arkascha I've updated the post with the core dump.

Comment: Looks like you have a strange issue with compatibility between `libio` and your `php` executable. What kind of system is that and how did you install php?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 on Intel 64 bit, php installed with apt-get. The problem is only with normal users, not with root.